# Is there a value provider needed for a collection of string for Solr

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

is there a value provider needed for a collection of string for Solr?Is it provided out of the box or do we have to write our own value provider for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `springELValueProvider` combined with [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (SpEL).

1. If we suppose your collection called `myCollection` :

```java
public class ProductModel {

    //...

    List<String> myCollection;

    //...

}
```

2. Then create a `SolrIndexedProperty` as follow :

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty   ; name[unique=true] ;type(code) ;multiValue[default=false]  ;fieldValueProvider     ;valueProviderParameter
                                    ; myCollection      ;string     ;true                       ;springELValueProvider  ;myCollection
```

Comment: @Rachit, This (also) is a right answer ! please .. mark it as a solution. You gonna get a badge, trust me!